# Common Interface for FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement with dynamic programming

Tags: c#, wpf, dynamic, frameworkelement

I try to cut it short: FrameworkElement and FrameworkContentElement share a lot of the same API but do not have a common Interface. Only DependencyObject as a base class.

I've come across [this implementation of IFrameworkElement](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/wpf-series-iframeworkelement---the-missing-interface), which manually adds an interface and two wrapper classes. Now this code comes is implemented in .NET 3.5 and the author remarks that it would be a lot easier to do with dynamic programming in .NET 4:

> The actual code is very simple, but about 624 lines long for each element. (It will be a much simpler one line implementation in a dynamic language - C# 4.0 is coming :) ).

I would be very curious how an implementation of that would look like. I assume it would boil down to a dynamic implementation of `IFrameworkElement`, and read about `ExpandoObject` and `DynamicObject` to see if I could implement myself, but I'm a bit stumped. I guess one can write a custom implementation of DynamicObject - but that isn't a one liner. Could this be really made *that* easy with dynamic programming? I doesn't even need to be a one liner, I'd be fine with 10 or even 100 lines instead of the original 1250.

I'm thinking something like this:

```
// Example, not working:
public IFrameworkElement AsFrameworkElement(FrameworkElement ele)
{
  dynamic ife = ele as IFrameworkElement;
  return ife;    
}

IFrameworkElement frameworkElement = AsFrameworkElement(new Button());
frameworkElement.DataContext = "Whatever";

IFrameworkElement frameworkContentElement = AsFrameworkElement(new Paragraph());
frameworkContentElement.DataContext = "Whatever again";
```

Comment: Whats with the code snippets on that site? They are overlapping for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what exactly the author of that article meant (maybe we should ask him/her), but I guess it needs a little bit more than one line of code.
The point is that the [dynamic keyword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/dd264741.aspx) (new with 4.0 .NET) allows the so called [duck typing](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

The article's author had to write 2 wrapper classes in order to make `FrameworkElement` and `FrameworkContentElement` implement the `IFrameworkElement` interface.

Now with `dynamic` keywork we can write just class (for maintaining the *comfort of our interface*).

```
public interface IFrameworkElement
{
    /* Let's suppose we have just one property, since it is a sample */
    object DataContext
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class FrameworkElementImpl : IFrameworkElement
{
    private readonly dynamic target;

    public FrameworkElementImpl(dynamic target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public object DataContext
    {
        get
        {
            return target.DataContext;
        }
        set
        {
            target.DataContext = value;
        }
    }
}

public static class DependencyObjectExtension
{
    public static IFrameworkElement AsIFrameworkElement(this DependencyObject dp)
    {
        if (dp is FrameworkElement || dp is FrameworkContentElement)
        {
            return new FrameworkElementImpl(dp);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

So now we can write in our code something like:

```
System.Windows.Controls.Button b = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
IFrameworkElement ife = b.AsIFrameworkElement();

ife.DataContext = "it works!";

Debug.Assert(b.DataContext == ife.DataContext);
```

Now if you do not want to write your wrapper (or proxy as you wish) class (i.e. `FrameworkElementImpl` in our sample), there are some libraries that do it for you ([impromptu-interface](https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface) or [Castle DynamicProxy](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)).

You can find [here](http://bugsquash.blogspot.it/2009/05/duck-typing-with-castle-dynamicproxy.html) a very simple example which makes use of Castle DynamicProxy:

```
public class Duck
{
    public void Quack()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Quack Quack!");
    }

    public void Swim()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Swimming...");
    }
}

public interface IQuack
{
    void Quack();
}

public interface ISwimmer
{
    void Swim();
}

public static class DuckTypingExtensions
{
    private static readonly ProxyGenerator generator = new ProxyGenerator();

    public static T As<T>(this object o)
    {
        return generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<T>(new DuckTypingInterceptor(o));
    }
}

public class DuckTypingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly object target;

    public DuckTypingInterceptor(object target)
    {
        this.target = target;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var methods = target.GetType().GetMethods()
            .Where(m => m.Name == invocation.Method.Name)
            .Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == invocation.Arguments.Length)
            .ToList();
        if (methods.Count > 1)
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("Ambiguous method match for '{0}'", invocation.Method.Name));
        if (methods.Count == 0)
            throw new ApplicationException(string.Format("No method '{0}' found", invocation.Method.Name));
        var method = methods[0];
        if (invocation.GenericArguments != null && invocation.GenericArguments.Length > 0)
            method = method.MakeGenericMethod(invocation.GenericArguments);
        invocation.ReturnValue = method.Invoke(target, invocation.Arguments);
    }
}
```

As you can see, in this case, with a few lines of code you can obtain the same result that the author obtained with

> about 624 lines [...] for each element

Answer (score 2):

Look at the original code of the blog:

```
var dataContect = "DataContext";
var frameworkElement = sender as FrameworkElement;
if ( frameworkElement != null )
{
    frameworkElement.DataContext = dataContect;
}
else
{
    var frameworkContentElement = sender as FrameworkContentElement;
    if ( frameworkContentElement != null )
    {
        frameworkContentElement.DataContext = dataContect;
    }
}
```

It would become

```
var dataContext = "DataContext"
dynamic element = sender;
element.DataContext = dataContext;
```

That's it already. At runtime, a property with the name `DataContext` will be searched for by reflection (be careful: when it comes to lists of dynamic types, things might slow down terribly), and then it is invoked.

Note: if the property does not exist, a `RuntimeBinderException` will be thrown. You might add some try...catch around the last line.

Comment: But that won't give me the comfort of the IFrameworkElement interface. Sure I can invoke all members from a dynamic variable if I know the name, but I was thinking I would be able to "convert" the two objects, so I can pick the available members from the interface.

Comment: @Lennart For the comfort when writing your code, use one concrete class, such that intellisense will work. Afterwards, replace it with `dynamic`.

Comment: It won't give you the performance benefit of concrete classes either, but it is the right answer.

Comment: Did you think of something like `IFrameworkElement = dynamic_cast(sender, typeof(IFrameworkElement));`? Well, that would be nice, but it is not the way Microsoft implemented dynamic features. Perhaps we could suggest that to them.